# bc command in bash scripts returns error on Jenkins server however runs fine in local

Tags: bash, jenkins, sed, bc

I have below lines of code in my bash script which reads a file line by line and compares its float value with the given threshold. 
This code works just fine on local (mac system) and returns the correct output.

```
   ........
   ........
   cat perf/perftestresult.txt | sed -n "s/^.*throughput]\\s*\\(.*,\\s\\)\\(.*\\)/\\2/p" > 
   $filename

   buildFailed=false
   while IFS= read -r line
    do
        if [ 1 -eq "$( echo "${line} < ${threshold}" | bc )" ]
        then 
            buildFailed=true
            break
        else
            continue
        fi
    done < "$filename"
    echo $buildFailed
    .......
    .......
```

However, the same script returns below error when run in Jenkins pipeline.

```
line 141: 1: not found
12:53:51  sh: out of range
```

Line 141 in script is the If condition

Can someone please help me fix this issue?

Comment: Either `line` isn't set (did you read an empty line?) or you failed to assign a value to `threshold`.

Comment: Hmm! Good start. I will print the value of threshold and line.

Comment: bc command is working fine now. the variable threshold was read as empty string so the error was coming. 
However, the second issue (shown below) remains now.
```line 141: 1: not found 12:53:51 sh: out of range```

 - line 141 is the if condition